# JavaScript Decorator pattern. Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, recursion, decorator

Here is a working example of Decorator pattern:

```
class Dummy {
    run() {
        console.log('run');
    }
}

function get() {
    let instance = new Dummy();
    instance.run = ((func) => {
        return function() {
            func();
            console.log('decorator run');    
        }
    })(instance.run);

    return instance;
}

let obj = get();
obj.run();
```

However, if we change the *get* function to:

```
function get() {
    let instance = new Dummy();
    instance.run = function() {
        instance.run();
        console.log('decorator run');  
    }       

    return instance;
}
```

we will be faced with an error:
    *VM68418:6 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Dummy.instance.run (:6:32)*

Why is this happening? The *instance.run* is still a wrapper around the original method, without 'useless' additional self executed function.

I will be glad to hear the answer

Comment: Seems like it is causing a never ending recursion.

Comment: Because you call `instance.run` from inside `instance.run`. And this is endless recusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, the current value of `instance.run` is retained in the `func` closed variable, then `instance.run` is assigned a new value::

```
instance.run = <old function>
func = instance.run
instance.run = <new function>
// func === <old function> here
```

So when `instance.run` invokes `func`, it essentially invokes `<old function>`.

You can do the same without IIFE, by simply closing `func` in `get()`:

```js
class Dummy {
    run() {
        console.log('run');
    }
}

function get() {
    let instance = new Dummy();
    
    let func = instance.run;
    instance.run = function() {
       func();
       console.log('decorator run');    
    }
    
    return instance;
}

let obj = get();
obj.run();
```

In the second snippet, `instance.run` old value is lost and it effectively invokes itself causing a stack overflow.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I thought that function like object passes as reference. Therefore if it a full copying it looks logically

Answer (score 3):

`instance.run()` is being called inside its own definitation, so it is causing a never ending recursion, hence causing a **Maximum call stack size exceeded** error.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's dangerous to get tangled in made-up things like "decorators", "decorator pattern", or even "patterns". At the core of your issue, you have a function whose behaviour you wish to alter, or `decorate`...

```js
const original = x =>
  x * x
  
const decorate = f =>
  x => f (x) + 1
  
const decorated =
  decorate (original)

console.log (original (4))  // 16   4 * 4
console.log (decorated (4)) // 17   (4 * 4) + 1
```

So with `decorate`, we're capturing this incrementing `+ 1` effect, but notice we were forced to decide when to increment; *before* or *after* the original function was called. Maybe in a different variation, we want to "decorate" using this +1 effect but at the opposite time.

Below, `firstAdd1` is a "decorator" that increments *before* the original function is called. `thenAdd1` is a decorator that increments *after* the original function is called.

```js
const original = x =>
  x * x
  
const thenAdd1 = f =>
  x => f (x) + 1

const firstAdd1 = f =>
  x => f (x + 1)
  
const decoratedA =
  thenAdd1 (original)

const decoratedB =
  firstAdd1 (original)
  
console.log (original (4))   // 16   4 * 4
console.log (decoratedA (4)) // 17   (4 * 4) + 1
console.log (decoratedB (4)) // 25   (4 + 1) * (4 + 1)
```

But now we've sort of duplicated the +1 effect. "Decorating" as it turns out, is just [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition). Realizing this, we remove pain and suffering from our program.

Below, we capture our +1 effect in a pure function, `add1`, and then simply *compose* it before or after a given `f`

```
const add1 = x =>
  x + 1

const compose = (f, g) =>
  x => f (g (x))

const thenAdd1 = f =>
  compose (add1, f)

const firstAdd1 = f =>
  compose (f, add1)
```

No objects were harmed in the making of this program

```js
const original = x =>
  x * x

const add1 = x =>
  x + 1
  
const compose = (f, g) =>
  x => f (g (x))

const thenAdd1 = f =>
  compose (add1, f)

const firstAdd1 = f =>
  compose (f, add1)
  
const decoratedA =
  thenAdd1 (original)

const decoratedB =
  firstAdd1 (original)
  
console.log (original (4))   // 16   4 * 4
console.log (decoratedA (4)) // 17   (4 * 4) + 1
console.log (decoratedB (4)) // 25   (4 + 1) * (4 + 1)
```

Of course function composition is massively powerful. We can modify `compose` to accept an arbitrary number of functions. Now we can sequence any number of effects in any order of our choosing. Here, we also skip the intermediate creation of "decorators" and instead define "decorated" functions directly in terms of `compose`

```js
const original = x =>
  x * x

const add1 = x =>
  x + 1
  
const compose = (f, ...fs) => x =>
  f === undefined
    ? x
    : f (compose (...fs) (x))

const decoratedA =
  compose (add1, original, add1)
  
const decoratedB =
  compose (add1, add1, add1, original, original)

const decoratedC =
  compose (decoratedB, decoratedA)
  
console.log (original (4))   // 16       4 * 4
console.log (decoratedA (4)) // 26       ((4 + 1) * (4 + 1)) + 1
console.log (decoratedB (4)) // 259      ((4 * 4) * (4 * 4)) + 1 + 1 + 1
console.log (decoratedC (4)) // 456979   (((((4 + 1) * (4 + 1)) + 1) * (((4 + 1) * (4 + 1)) + 1)) * ((((4 + 1) * (4 + 1)) + 1) * (((4 + 1) * (4 + 1)) + 1))) + 1 + 1 + 1
```

Yep, because `compose` returns a *new* function, we can even make compositions of other compositions. Even compose side-effecting functions like `console.log` using `effect` which guarantees the output matches the input

Below `logger` allows us to visualize any particular function's impact by logging the result to the `console` before returning the final value – to this end, you *could* say `logger (f)` *decorates* `f` by adding a logging behaviour – but it's just classical function composition

```js
const square = x =>
  x * x

const add1 = x =>
  x + 1
  
const compose = (f, ...fs) => x =>
  f === undefined
    ? x
    : f (compose (...fs) (x))
      
const effect = f => x =>
  (f (x), x)
  
const logger = f =>
  compose (effect (console.log), f)

const main =
  compose (logger (add1), logger (square))

console.log (main (4))
// 16     (console.log side effect)
// 17     (console.log side effect)
// => 17  (return value)
```

If you're writing OO-style with classes and methods, it doesn't matter; `compose` is still your go-to

```js
const compose = (f, ...fs) => x =>
  f === undefined
    ? x
    : f (compose (...fs) (x))
      
const effect = f => x =>
  (f (x), x)

const addExcitement = x =>
  x + '!'
  
const capitalize = x =>
  x.toUpperCase ()

class Person {
  constructor (name) {
    this.name = name
  }
  greet () {
    return `I am ${this.name}`
  }
}

// "decorator"
const Shouter =
  effect (m => 
    m.greet = compose (addExcitement, capitalize, m.greet.bind(m)))

const p = new Person ('me')
console.log (p.greet ())    // I am me

Shouter (p)
console.log (p.greet ())    // I AM ME!
```

Comment: if your function is a member of an object, that doesn't really change anything. `compose` gives you the power to sequence *any* functions

Comment: It might be helpful to expand `// 456979` into the nested function that output that value instead, since it's not entirely clear why that's "expected" in the example. Same goes for `// 259`

Comment: Thanks for your comment @PatrickRoberts – I added some notes to show expanded evaluations

Comment: Thank you a lot for your examples!